# PHP Inheretence of methods through multiple layers of classes

Tags: php

I have code that when heavily boiled down, looks pretty much like this:

```php
abstract class Car {
    public abstract static function parts();
    protected static function getParts() {
        $parts = [];
        $properties = (new ReflectionClass(static::class))->getProperties();
        foreach ($properties as $property) {
            $parts[] = $property->getName();
        }
        return $parts;
    }
}
class Ford extends car {
    public $wheels;
    public $body;
    public static function parts() {
        return self::getParts();
    }
}
class FordTruck extends Ford {
    public $truckBed;
}

function getBaseParts($cartype) {
    return $cartype::parts();
}
```

But when I call `getBaseParts("FordTruck")` I get back

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "truckBed"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "wheels"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "body"
}
```

In reality, I only want back "wheels" and "body", not the 'extraneous' stuff that's added in classes past `Ford`. I thought that creating a `parts()` method in the class whose parts I care about, that then calls `self::getParts()`, which in turn gets the properties from `static` would mean that the class that 'static' is referring to would be the `Ford` class. But it's more like it's calling `parts()` from the `FordTruck` class.

Is there a way I can get the functionality I'm looking for with this setup? The 'easiest' way I can think of would be moving the 'getParts()' method into the `Ford` class and have it call a reflectionclass of self, but I have dozens of classes that extend `Ford` that would all just be copied code if I fixed it that way.

Comment: Would something like `return Ford::getParts();` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

static::class is always going to return the 'lowest level' class that the object in question is instantiated as. As such, static::class is always going to return FordTruck even though it's defined in Car and the function itself is called in Ford

On the other hand, self::class returns the classname of the class it's *defined* in. So self::class in Ford is going to return Ford, even though the object is technically a FordTruck.

The easiest way to get the functionality you want is to pass the value of self::class from Ford to getParts() and use that in your Reflection.

So, for example:

```
<?php
     abstract class Car {
        public abstract static function parts();
        protected static function getParts(string $className) {
            $parts = [];
            $properties = (new ReflectionClass($className))->getProperties();
            foreach ($properties as $property) {
                $parts[] = $property->getName();
            }
            return $parts;
        }
    }
    class Ford extends Car {
        public $wheels;
        public $body;
        public static function parts() {
            return self::getParts(self::class);
        }
    }
    class FordTruck extends Ford {
        public $truckBed;
    }
    
    function getBaseParts($cartype) {
        return $cartype::parts();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not really fan of this solution, you rather change the mindset behind your solution, but here is a simple solution to you problem here

```
<?php

abstract class Car {
    public abstract static function parts();
    protected static function getParts($class = null) {
        return array_keys(get_class_vars($class ?? static::class));
    }
}
class Ford extends car {
    public $wheels;
    public $body;
    public static function parts() {
        return self::getParts(Ford::class);
    }
}
class FordTruck extends Ford {
    public $truckBed;
}

function getBaseParts($cartype) {
    return $cartype::parts();
}

var_dump(getBaseParts("FordTruck"));
```

Test : https://3v4l.org/s8Aar

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find this 'workaround' which works, but I'm not too sure it's the best solution.

```php
abstract class Car {
    public static function getParts() {
        $carModel = array_reverse(array_values(class_parents(static::class)))[1];
        $parts = [];
        $properties = (new ReflectionClass(new $carModel))->getProperties();
        foreach ($properties as $property) {
            $parts[] = $property->getName();
        }
        return $parts;
    }
}
class Ford extends car {
    public $wheels;
    public $body;
}
class FordTruck extends Ford {
    public $truckBed;
}

function getBaseParts($cartype) {
    return $cartype::getParts();
}

getBaseParts("FordTruck");
```